# Ensure page is accessed from a specific link

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Say if I have link1.aspx and link2.aspx.  Within link1.aspx, I redirect the user to link2.aspx.

What is the most efficient way of checking that link2.aspx is only accessed via link1.aspx?

For example, something like:

link2.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if page is not accessed via link1.aspx
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/portal.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

I could use a query string but are there any other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **UrlReferrer**. However, it is not a secure way of detecting where the user comes from.

For example,

```
if (string.Equals(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri,
    "YOUR_REFERRER_URL",
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{

}
```

If it is redirecting between pages inside your application, I would like to suggest to use **SessionState** which is more secure and robust than **UrlReferrer**.

### link1.aspx.cs

```
private bool IsValidUrl
{
    set { Session["IsValidUrl"] = true; }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsValidUrl = true;
    Response.Redirect("link2.aspx");
}
```

### link2.aspx.cs

```
private bool IsValidUrl
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["IsValidUrl"] != null)
            return Convert.ToBoolean(Session["IsValidUrl"]);
        return false;
    }
    set { Session["IsValidUrl"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValidUrl)
    {
        // user comes from valid url. 
        // .... Do somthing

        // Reset session state value
        IsValidUrl = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`Request.UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx) property to check what page the user is coming from.

Comment: Note that `UrlReferrer` is not reliable.